# spring web tomcat setup

Tags: xml, spring, configuration

I hope someone can help me with this issue.
I have uploaded the spring example that I'm working on so that it will be easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically I want to creata a spring web restful service and I'm trying to put pieces together.
I have manged to use jpa,I can call the database (mysql) and get data; I tested this using the Main class.
Now I want to add an interface(index.html) and use controller to retrieve data from the database(restful service)
However, I'm having problems with the configuration.
Here's the project
http://www.sendspace.com/file/so37f1

Can you guys help me with the following:

I'm trying to set a custom page so that when I start tomcat, it will go to index.html and from there I can make various call. 
How can I set the custom page
Is it there anything that I'm missing in the configuarion? because when I try to run it on server I get the following errror

```
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Mar 27 23:24:32 GMT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringDataJpa\WEB-INF\classes\com\springdata\repositories\CustomerRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringDataJpa\WEB-INF\classes\com\springdata\repositories\CustomerRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.handleError(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringDataJpa\WEB-INF\classes\com\springdata\repositories\CustomerRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-commons-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:53) ~[spring-data-commons-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:69) ~[spring-data-commons-1.6.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.34]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:63) ~[spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80) ~[spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) ~[spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Mar 27, 2014 11:24:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringDataJpa\WEB-INF\classes\com\springdata\repositories\CustomerRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringDataJpa\WEB-INF\classes\com\springdata\repositories\CustomerRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.handleError(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\SpringDataJpa\WEB-INF\classes\com\springdata\repositories\CustomerRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:69)
    ... 30 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a smaller project that doesn't include datasource, otherwise it's hard to reproduce your problem as I wouldn't know what your database schema is.

Comment: The following is a simpler version, what I want to achieve is being able to change the welcome page. I've read about welcom-list and tried to apply them but it doesn't work.
It contains an index.htm file that I've created, how can I configure the system so that when you go to http://localhost:8080/WebTest/ , it will show the index.htm homepage?
http://www.sendspace.com/file/xli1jy

Answer (score 0):

*how can I configure the system so that when you go to localhost:8080/WebTest , it will show the index.htm homepage?*

You need to create a controller with a handler method that maps request to / to some view name (eg: "index")

```
@Controller
public class IndexController
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

And create the file `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/index.htm`. This will be mapped into `localhost:8080/WebTest/index.htm` because in mvc-config.xml you already have a view resolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".htm"/>
</bean>
```

Please read the reference doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: I have done as you said but it doesn't work.
I created a controller mapping "/"
index.html in view folder but when I run the service nothing happens
if I got to webtest/index.html even then I get 404 error and the console states no mapping found.

Comment: Sorry it's too hard to debug, if you can upload your project using dropbox / sendspace and share it it'll help.